# fprintf is not writing the file as it displays - matlab

Tags: matlab, file-io, printf

the code below displays at the matlab command panel perfectly well

```
fprintf('%f\n%f\n%f\n',MDR,TER,FAR);
```

each variable is displayed as new line

but when i try this way and check the newly made text file via notepad i don't see any new lines

```
fileID=fopen('my_file.txt','w');
fprintf(fileID,'%f\n%f\n%f\n',MDR,TER,FAR);
fclose(fileID);
```

what might be the problem ? at the text file all variables are written without any new line or space

thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the backslash in the filename I assume that you are working on a windows platform. Unix and Windows use different new line characters. Windows uses `\r\n` as new line while Linux and OSX use `\n`. Matlab on the other hand uses Unix new lines in the command panel.

You might want to use `dlmwrite` to write your text files. This is generally more reliable and faster than `fprintf`.

Example:

```
dlmwrite('my_file.txt',[MDR;TER;FAR],'newline','pc')
```

the important part is that the input `[MDR;TER;FAR]` is a matrix. Every row will be on a new line and the columns are separated by the standard delimeter `,`.

Comment: i could not manage dlmwrite. can you also post its syntax here. i mean modify the upper example with dlmwrite. thank you.